# $M\le \max_{t\in [0,1]}|at+b\sin t-t^2|\;\;,\;\;\forall \;a,b\in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: inequality

Calculate the best value of $M$
$$\large M\le \max_{t\in [0,1]}|at+b\sin t-t^2|\;\;,\;\;\forall \;a,b\in \mathbb{R}$$
Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

The vector space of continuous functions defined on the interval $[0,1]$ endowed with the norm
$$||f||=\max_{t\in[0,1]}|f(t)|$$
is a Banach space and the set 
$$F=\{at+b\sin t,\  a,b\in\mathbb{R}\}$$
is a closed subspace so  by what notion we can find $a_0$ and $b_0$ such that
$$||a_0t+b_0\sin t-t^2||\leq ||at+b\sin t-t^2||\quad \forall a,b\in\mathbb R?$$ 
and what represents the function $t\mapsto a_0t+b_0\sin t$ for the function $t\mapsto t^2$?

Comment: But $(C[0,1],||\cdot||)$ is not Hilbert space.

Comment: Surely I wanted to say Banach space.

Answer (score 0):

To get an upper bound for $M$, find values of $a,b$ such that the derivative is non-zero on $[0,1]$, (i.e. $b \cos t \neq 2t-a$ on $[0,1]$). Then the max must be at an endpoint. Still adhering to the first condition, try to minimize $|f(1)|$.